# the inverting amplifier get wrong voltage in output

Tags: operational-amplifier

as I know I should get -5 mV in this circuit. (OPAMp is ideal), but in this simulation with an ideal op amp in PSpice, my output voltage is -15 volt, can any one help me?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In PSpice "M" and "m" stand for milli. To indicate megaohm, write "meg".

This is why your output saturates. You're feeding with "almost a short" (ok, 1 milliOhm) 5V to the inverting input and 0 to the non inverting. That way you're just using the OP AMP as a comparator (the 1kOhm resistor is nothing more than a load).
By the way, the gain (with the 1-mOhm resistor) in fact would be -1E6.

Comment: thanks for your help, 1Mega ohm resistor is my sensor in fact, that I want to measure it is current